# Kivy apps running at 0.2 fps

Tags: gui

recently all my apps in Kivy started running on 0.2 fps… the only thing I have done to my computer was to install the newest update of league of legends... below is the output from the debug mode when I start an app.

```
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in   C:\Users\jk_ju\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-07-06_0.txt
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
    [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\jk_ju\Anaconda3 \lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
    [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\jk_ju\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe"
    [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
    [DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
    [DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
    [DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
    [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
    [DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
    [DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
    [DEBUG  ] [GL          ] available extensions: b'GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_texture3D GL_EXT_clip_volume_hint GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_ARB_multitexture GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_conservative_depth GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_internalformat_query2 GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_NV_blend_square GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_window_pos GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_WIN_swap_hint GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_NV_conditional_render GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_texture_gather GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_EXT_transform_feedback GL_ARB_transform_feedback2 GL_ARB_draw_indirect GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_ARB_blend_func_extended GL_INTEL_performance_queries GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend GL_ARB_geometry_shader4 GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 GL_ARB_texture_query_lod GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_base_instance GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32 GL_ARB_compatibility GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_texture_multisample GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_ARB_timer_query GL_ARB_tessellation_shader GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sample_shading GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 GL_ARB_gpu_shader5 GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 GL_ARB_shader_subroutine GL_ARB_transform_feedback3 GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects GL_ARB_shader_precision GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit GL_ARB_viewport_array GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters GL_ARB_shading_language_packing GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_EXT_texture_storage GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect GL_ARB_program_interface_query GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample GL_ARB_buffer_storage GL_ARB_debug_output GL_KHR_debug GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays GL_INTEL_map_texture GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility GL_ARB_robustness GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_ARB_stencil_texturing '
    [DEBUG  ] [GL          ] glShaderBinary is not available
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4425'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.00 - Build 10.18.10.4425'>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
    [DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
    [DEBUG  ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
    [DEBUG  ] [ImageSDL2   ] Load <C:\Users\jk_ju\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
    [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
    [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
    [DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add <C:\WINDOWS\Fonts> in path list
    [DEBUG  ] [Resource    ] add <C:\Users\jk_ju\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\fonts> in path list
    [DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <textinput.label> with limit=None, timeout=60.0
    [DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <textinput.width> with limit=None, timeout=60.0
    [DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Load <C:\Users\jk_ju\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\images\defaulttheme.atlas>
    [DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Need to load 1 images
    [DEBUG  ] [Atlas       ] Load <C:\Users\jk_ju\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\images\defaulttheme-0.png>
    [DEBUG  ] [ImageSDL2   ] Load <C:\Users\jk_ju\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\images\defaulttheme-0.png>
    [DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <C:/Users/jk_ju/Anaconda3/Scripts\mymain.kv>
    [DEBUG  ] [App         ] kv <C:/Users/jk_ju/Anaconda3/Scripts\mymain.kv> not found
    [DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from mouse
    [DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from wm_touch
    [DEBUG  ] [Base        ] Create provider from wm_pen
    [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
    [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
    [INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
    [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Comment: 10.18.10.4425 is 3 years old - maybe update graphics drivers?

Comment: I checked for updates using hp official driver updater and it said I had the newest graphic driver :S

Comment: Don't use the laptop maker [or Windows either], use Intel directly. The makers can't be bothered after about a year.

Comment: Used intels updater, didnt find any new updates :(